i was trying o build a stack using aws cdk , application load balancer with two ec2 instance
 @jsii/kernel.SerializationError: Passed to parameter props of new aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationTargetGroup: Unable to deserialize value as aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationTargetGroupProps | undefined
  ├──  Failing value is an object
  │      { '$jsii.struct': [Object] }
  ╰──  Failure reason(s):
      ╰─ Key 'targets': Unable to deserialize value as array<aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.IApplicationLoadBalancerTarget> | undefined
          ├──  Failing value is an array
          │      [ '${Token[TOKEN.111]}', '${Token[TOKEN.137]}' ]
          ╰──  Failure reason(s):
              ╰─ Index 0: Unable to deserialize value as aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.IApplicationLoadBalancerTarget
                  ├──  Failing value is a string
                  │      '${Token[TOKEN.111]}'
                  ╰──  Failure reason(s):
                      ╰─ Value does not have the "$jsii.byref" key
      at Object.process (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\tmptnruo9od\lib\program.js:11477:19)
      at Kernel._Kernel_toSandbox (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\tmptnruo9od\lib\program.js:10455:25)
      at C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\tmptnruo9od\lib\program.js:10471:38
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at Kernel._Kernel_boxUnboxParameters (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\tmptnruo9od\lib\program.js:10471:23)
      at Kernel._Kernel_toSandboxValues (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\tmptnruo9od\lib\program.js:10459:101)
      at Kernel._Kernel_create (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\tmptnruo9od\lib\program.js:10119:115)
      at Kernel.create (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\tmptnruo9od\lib\program.js:9790:93)
      at KernelHost.processRequest (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\tmptnruo9od\lib\program.js:11707:36)
      at KernelHost.run (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\tmptnruo9od\lib\program.js:11667:22)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\AWS Devops\CDK\app.py", line 10, in <module>
    CdkEc2Stack(app, "CdkEc2Stack")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jsii\_runtime.py", line 118, in __call__
    inst = super(JSIIMeta, cast(JSIIMeta, cls)).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\AWS Devops\CDK\cdk\cdk_stack.py", line 134, in __init__
    target_group = elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jsii\_runtime.py", line 118, in __call__
    inst = super(JSIIMeta, cast(JSIIMeta, cls)).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\aws_cdk\aws_elasticloadbalancingv2\__init__.py", line 22906, in __init__
    jsii.create(self.__class__, self, [scope, id, props])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jsii\_kernel\__init__.py", line 334, in create
    response = self.provider.create(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jsii\_kernel\providers\process.py", line 365, in create
    return self._process.send(request, CreateResponse)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jsii\_kernel\providers\process.py", line 342, in send
    raise RuntimeError(resp.error) from JavaScriptError(resp.stack)
RuntimeError: Passed to parameter props of new aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationTargetGroup: Unable to deserialize value as aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationTargetGroupProps | undefined
├──  Failing value is an object
│      { '$jsii.struct': [Object] }
╰──  Failure reason(s):
    ╰─ Key 'targets': Unable to deserialize value as array<aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.IApplicationLoadBalancerTarget> | undefined
        ├──  Failing value is an array
        │      [ '${Token[TOKEN.111]}', '${Token[TOKEN.137]}' ]
        ╰──  Failure reason(s):
            ╰─ Index 0: Unable to deserialize value as aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.IApplicationLoadBalancerTarget
                ├──  Failing value is a string
                │      '${Token[TOKEN.111]}'
                ╰──  Failure reason(s):
                    ╰─ Value does not have the "$jsii.byref" key

THIS IS MY ACTUAL CODE
alb = elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(
    self,
    "MyALB",
    vpc=vpc,
    internet_facing=True,
    security_group=sec_group,
    load_balancer_name="MyALB",
)

# Add Listener to ALB
listener = alb.add_listener(
    "Listener",
    port=80,
    open=True,
)

target_group = elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(
    self,
    "TargetGroup",
    vpc=vpc,
    port=80,
    targets=[instance1.instance_id, instance2.instance_id],
    health_check=elbv2.HealthCheck(
        path="/",
        interval=Duration.seconds(60)
    )
)

listener.add_targets(
    "ListenerTargetGroup",
    target_groups=[target_group]
)

# Output the ALB DNS Name
CfnOutput(self, "LoadBalancerDNS", value=alb.load_balancer_dns_name)


The targets prop in ApplicationTargetGroup expects a list of IApplicationLoadBalancerTarget, and you're passing a list of strings.
Use InstanceTarget:
target_group = elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(
    self,
    "TargetGroup",
    ...
    targets=[
        elbv2_targets.InstanceTarget(instance1),
        elbv2_targets.InstanceTarget(instance2),
    ],
    ...
)


I think that you must define your instance with instanceTarget
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2_targets.InstanceTarget.html
    # Add Target Group to Listener
    target_group = listener.add_targets(
        "ListenerTargetGroup",
        port=80,
        targets=[
            elbv2_targets.InstanceIdTarget(instance1.instance_id),
            elbv2_targets.InstanceIdTarget(instance2.instance_id)
        ],
        health_check=elbv2.HealthCheck(
            path="/",
            interval=Duration.seconds(60)
        )
    )

